# Make a bingo table in Android xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to create a large square and inside the large square there will be 25 small squares.I am using a png image of the square with small 25 squares in it and using linear and linear horizontal to align the large text view inside the square. But when I change the device screen the text comes out of the boundary of the png image square.
Is there any solution for this?
[This the square image i am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcsBv.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.nijinsha.bingomultiplayer.Game_Act"
    android:background="@drawable/bkgd"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="340dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/bgrid"
        android:background="@drawable/gdbk"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="340dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="68.5dp"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="62dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="02"
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="50sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="62dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="05"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="50sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit
The problem is with devices which is not HD

Comment: try to remove padding

Comment: the problem is only on smaller devices with screen size smaller than 5 inch

Comment: try to add scrollView

Comment: what you need is, make images with different size as per resolution of devices than add scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the width of the imageView. I  changed the width to 300 and now no problem. The problem was imageView was at its maximum and could not be bigger on low pixel density devices.